# Proof of an identity - Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a measurable set and  $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$ a measurable positive function. Prove that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{E} (f(x))^{1/n} dx =\lambda (E)
$$
where $\lambda$ denotes the (positive) Lebesgue measure.

*SOME CONTEXT:*

**My definition of Lebesgue Measure:** Firstly, it can be proved that any open set can be expressed as the union of disjoint diadic cubes, which their closure is contained in the open set (I don't prove it, but this decomposition always exists). Due to this, I define the measure of an open set $G\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $m(G)$, as the sum of the volumes of the intervals in the previously commented decomposition. Then, on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, I define the outer Lebesgue measure, $\lambda^{*}$, which I define as following: given $A\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, $\lambda^{*}(A)=\inf\{m(G): G\textrm{ is open}, A\subseteq G\}$. Then, defining that $A$ is a Lebesgue-measurable set if, given $\epsilon >0$, $\exists G$ open set and $\exists F$ closed set such that $F\subseteq A\subseteq G$ and $m(G\setminus F)<\epsilon$, I verify that the subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ formed by the Lebesgue-measurable sets, which I call $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, is a $\sigma$- algebra. Then, the Lebesgue (positive) measure, $\lambda$, is just the restriction of $\lambda^{*}$ to $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

**Definition:** $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm \infty\}$ is a measurable function if $[f<a]=f^{-1}((\infty,a))=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:f(x)<a\}\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ (where we consider $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, as the tern $(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n}),\lambda)$, where $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra formed by the measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $\lambda:\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\to [0,\infty)\cup \{\infty\}$ is the Lebesgue positive measure).

*ATTEMPT:*
Being able to "interchange limit and integral"' finishes the exercise, as $\lim_{n\to\infty} (f(x))^{1/n}=1$. That is the point that gets me more confused. I have tried to apply the dominated convergence theorem, as well as the monotone convergence theorem (that works for non-negative measurable functions).

Firstly, it is trivial to show that $f^{1/n}$ is a measurable function for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, using the fact that $f$ is measurable. Then, I have tried to define the function sequence $\{g_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, where $g_{n}=f^{1/n}$. This last sequence is monotonically decreasing, and this is the first point where I get lost, as the monotone convergence theorem applies for monotonically increasing sequences, not decreasing. So, I tried to change my strategy: if the sequence is monotonically decreasing, then $g_{1}\geq g_{n}$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. So, there is a measurable function $g_{1}$ that "dominates" the other ones. Having that this function is integrable (i.e., $\int_{E} g_{1}(x) dx <\infty$) gets the "interchanging lim-int" problem solved. But I cannot assure this with my hypothesis!

What am I missing? Someone could give me some hints? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If $E=(0,1)$ and $f(x)=e^{1/x}$, then $\int_E (f(x))^{1/n}\,dx=\infty$ for all $n$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Ok, I see... So the thing here is that the assumption is false! If I add the hypothesis that $\int_{E} f(x)dx <\infty$ (i.e., that $f(x)$ is integrable over $E$), then by the dominated convergence theorem, I would have the identity proved, no? Thanks for answering!

Comment: You have to divide into $E_1=\{x\in E\,:\, f(x)> 1\}$ and $E_2=\{x\in E\,:\, 0< f(x)\le1\}$. Then you can use dominated convergence theorem on $E_1$ and Beppo Levi on $E_2$.

Comment: In fact, if you look closely at the consideration above, you obtain that, given $f>0$, the limit is true as soon as $\lambda(E)=\infty$ or $f\in L^1(E)$.

Comment: Ok, I get the $E_{2}$ part... Nevertheless, why use Beppo Levi in $E_{1}$? Couldn't I just use dominated convergence theorem on the whole $E$, and arrive to the same conclusion? Thanks a lot for your time @SassatelliGiulio!

Comment: You use Beppo Levi on $E_2$, not $E_1$. $f^{1/n}\ge f$ on $E_2$, so it's unclear what the dominating function is supposed to be; in fact $f^{1/n}\to \textbf 1$ on $E_2$ (notice that you don't have $\lambda(E)<\infty$).

Comment: Ok, I see... Sorry for asking so much! And what is the non-decreasing sequence that you are considering when applying Beppo Levi's Lemma?